# Trying to create a deadlock between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

For creating  a deadlock in between two threads by accessing print method into Threads. I have used cyclic Barrier so that both of the thread starts at same time. If I am correct my print method is not taking time, for that reason it is getting shared by the two threads and not causing a Deadlock.

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class TWOTHREADDEADLOCLK {

    static int b =0;
    synchronized static void print()
    {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "     " + b);
    }
    synchronized static int  getb()
    {
        print();
        return b;
    }

    synchronized static void updateb()
    {
        print();
        b=b+10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final CyclicBarrier bar = new CyclicBarrier(2);
        Thread thread1  = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try {
                    bar.await();

                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch ( BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                while(true)
                    print();

            }

        });
        Thread thread2  = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {try {
                bar.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            while(true)
                getb();

            }

        });
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create a deadlock with a single barrier. The idea behind a deadlock is to have (at least) two threads, each one holding a different lock and attempting to take a lock on the other one. E.g., consider this simple example:

```
public class TwoLockRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Lock lockInConstructor;
    private Lock lockInRuntime;

    public TwoLockThread(Lock lockInConstructor, Lock lockInRuntime) {
        this.lockInConstructor = lockInConstructor;
        this.lockInRuntime = lockInRuntime;

        this.lockInConstructor.lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lockInRuntime.lock();

        System.out.println("After the lock in run()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
        Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

        TwoLockRunnable runnable1 = new TwoLockThread(lock1, lock2);
        TwoLockRunnable runnable2 = new TwoLockThread(lock2, lock1);

        new Thread(runnable1).start();
        new Thread(runnable2).start();
    }
}
```

The first thread locks `lock1` in its constructor and the second locks `lock2` in its constructor. The first thread then tries to lock `lock2` when its run - but it can't since lock is held by the other thread. Similarly, the second thread attempts to lock `lock1` when its run, and fails for the same reason. Thus, you get a deadlock, and the message `"After the lock in run()"` is never printed.

Answer (score 3):

like Mureinik's, this is the 'synchronized' demo:

```
public class DeadLockAATest {

static void methodA(DeadLockAATest d1, DeadLockAATest d2) {
    synchronized (d1) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (d2) {
            System.out.println("\t\t\tmethodA:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DeadLockAATest d1 = new DeadLockAATest(), d2 = new DeadLockAATest();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("t1-start:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            methodA(d1, d2);
            System.out.println("t1-end:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("t2-start:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            methodA(d2, d1);
            System.out.println("t2-end:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    System.out.println("deadlock...");
}
```

}

the deadlock output(just one contion, maybe t2 starts first):

```
t1-start:Thread-0
deadlock...
t2-start:Thread-1
```

you can replace

> methodA(d2, d1);

to

> methodA(d1, d2);

and this will output:

```
t1-start:Thread-0
t2-start:Thread-1
deadlock...
            methodA:Thread-0
t1-end:Thread-0
            methodA:Thread-1
t2-end:Thread-1
```

and this is not deadlock, hope to help you.